# Count number of specific categories in main inbox & all subfolders

Tags: vba, email, outlook, count, categories

I am trying to count the number of emails assigned a specific category that are in a shared inbox and its subfolders, in addition to the total email counts for each folder.

The code compiles, except for the sub CountCategories() and ProcessCatFolders().

I have a working version of CountCategories that counts the categories of email in the inbox folder and that prints into a new email.
It does not count the number of categorized emails in each subfolder.

When I add the recursion as ProcessCatFolders(), it will run, however my "gCateg" string does not print in the box of the new email.

```vb
Public gCateg As String
Public gFolders As String

Public Sub GetFolderNames()
Dim oSession As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oNewMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set oSession = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set oFolder = oSession.Folders("SOME_EMAIL@EMAIL.com").Folders("Inbox")

If (oFolder Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

ProcessFolder oFolder
CountCategories oFolder

Set oNewMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oNewMail.Subject = "EMAIL SUBJECT HERE "
oNewMail.Body = gCateg + gFolders
oNewMail.Display

gFolders = ""
gCateg = ""
End Sub


Sub ProcessFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

Dim i As Long
Dim oSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolderPaths As String

For i = CurrentFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders(i)

    sFolderPaths = oFolder
    gFolders = gFolders & vbCrLf & sFolderPaths & " " & oFolder.Items.Count
Next

For Each oSubFolder In CurrentFolder.Folders
    If oSubFolder.Name <> "Deleted Items" Then
        ProcessFolder oSubFolder
    End If
Next

End Sub


Sub CountCategories(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
Dim oSession As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim iCATEGORYa As Long
Dim iCATEGORYb As Long
Dim iCATEGORYc As Long
Dim iNone As Long

    iCATEGORYa = 0
    iCATEGORYb = 0
    iCATEGORYc = 0
    iNone = 0
    
    Set oSession = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oFolder = oSession.Folders("SOME_EMAIL@EMAIL.com").Folders("Inbox")

    If (oFolder Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    ProcessCatFolders oFolder

End Sub
         

Sub ProcessCatFolders(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oSession As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    For Each olItem In oFolder.Items
        Select Case olItem.Categories
            Case Is = "CATEGORYa": iCATEGORYa = iCATEGORYa + 1
            Case Is = "CATEGORYb": iCATEGORYb = iCATEGORYb + 1
            Case Is = "CATEGORYc": iCATEGORYc = iCATEGORYc + 1
            Case Else: iNone = iNone + 1
        End Select
        gCateg = "CATEGORYa : " & iCATEGORYa & vbCr & _
          "CATEGORYb : " & iCATEGORYb & vbCr & _
          "CATEGORYc : " & iCATEGORYc & vbCr & _
          "Unflagged: " & iNone & vbCr & _
          "" & vbCr

    Next olItem

    For Each oSubFolder In CurrentFolder.Folders
        If oSubFolder.Name <> "Deleted Items" Then
            ProcessCatFolders oSubFolder
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Case Is = "CATEGORYA": iCATEGORYa = iCATEGORYa + 1` is checking for 'CATEGORYA' and `CATEGORYa` is a different string, because of the last lowercased 'a'

Comment: Apologies -- this is a typo. In my actual code, I am using different category names and just quickly changed these for this post. I will correct my initial question

Comment: The error is the missing `On Error GoTo 0 ` to stop bypassing errors. Place it immediately after `Set oFolder = oSession.Folders("SOME_EMAIL@EMAIL.com").Folders("Inbox")`. Consider `On Error GoTo 0 ` mandatory and be wary of all code you find without it, or with many lines between it and `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Thank you, I added this, but it is still not resolving my issue

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Consider this mandatory. You will find you have to move iCATEGORY declaration and initialization to `ProcessCatFolders`. Now that errors are not hidden you will find `ProcessCatFolders` is not the same as `ProcessFolder`. Missing `For i = CurrentFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1` and `Set oFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders(i)`. If you cannot progress from there [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73576678/edit) the question with the new code to ask a focused question. Describe any error message and indicate the line on which the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've noticed that you pass an instance of the folder (see `CurrentFolder`) retrieved to the following function which doesn't use it:

```
Sub CountCategories(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
```

In the code the parameter is ignored and a new folder instance is retrieved.

Anyway, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
For Each olItem In oFolder.Items
        Select Case olItem.Categories
            Case Is = "CATEGORYa": iCATEGORYa = iCATEGORYa + 1
            Case Is = "CATEGORYb": iCATEGORYb = iCATEGORYb + 1
            Case Is = "CATEGORYc": iCATEGORYc = iCATEGORYc + 1
            Case Else: iNone = iNone + 1
        End Select
 gCateg = "CATEGORYa : " & iCATEGORYa & vbCr & _
    "CATEGORYb : " & iCATEGORYb & vbCr & _
    "CATEGORYc : " & iCATEGORYc & vbCr & _
    "Unflagged: " & iNone & vbCr & _
    "" & vbCr

    Next olItem
```

Instead, you may use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. In that case you can deal with only items that correspond to your conditions, for example, items that have a specific category or have any category assigned to them. You may apply a filter using the `Restrict` method and then count number of items found by checking the `Count` property of the `Items` collection returned as a result. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the developers blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about that method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the missing `On Error GoTo 0` to stop bypassing errors.

Place it immediately after

```
Set oFolder = oSession.Folders("SOME_EMAIL@EMAIL.com").Folders("Inbox")
```

Consider `On Error GoTo 0` mandatory and be wary of all code you find without it, or with many lines between it and `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Dim gCateg As String
Dim gFolders As String

Public Sub GetFolderNames()

Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim oNewMail As MailItem

On Error Resume Next
Set oFolder = Session.Folders("SOME_EMAIL@EMAIL.com").Folders("Inbox")
On Error GoTo 0     ' Consider mandatory after On Error Resume Next

If oFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Debug.Print oFolder.folderPath

If oFolder.Folders.count = 0 Then Exit Sub

ProcessCatStartFolder oFolder

gFolders = gFolders & vbCrLf & oFolder & " " & oFolder.Items.count
Debug.Print gFolders

processFolder oFolder
Debug.Print gFolders
ProcessCatFolders oFolder

Set oNewMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
oNewMail.subject = "EMAIL SUBJECT HERE "
oNewMail.Body = gCateg & vbCr & gFolders
oNewMail.Display

gFolders = ""
gCateg = ""

End Sub

Sub processFolder(currentFolder As Folder)

Dim i As Long
Dim oSubFolder As Folder
Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim sFolderPaths As String

For i = currentFolder.Folders.count To 1 Step -1
    Set oFolder = currentFolder.Folders(i)
    sFolderPaths = oFolder
    gFolders = gFolders & vbCrLf & sFolderPaths & " " & oFolder.Items.count
Next

For Each oSubFolder In currentFolder.Folders
    If oSubFolder.name <> "Deleted Items" Then
        processFolder oSubFolder
    End If
Next

End Sub
         

Sub ProcessCatFolders(currentFolder As Folder)

Dim iCATEGORYa As Long
Dim iCATEGORYb As Long
Dim iCATEGORYc As Long
Dim iNone As Long

Dim olItem As Object    ' A folder may contain other than mailitems

Dim oSubFolder As Folder
Dim oFolder As Folder
    
Dim categFolder As String

Dim i As Long

For i = currentFolder.Folders.count To 1 Step -1

    iCATEGORYa = 0
    iCATEGORYb = 0
    iCATEGORYc = 0
    iNone = 0

    Set oFolder = currentFolder.Folders(i)

    For Each olItem In oFolder.Items
    
        Select Case olItem.categories
            Case Is = "CATEGORYa"
                iCATEGORYa = iCATEGORYa + 1
                
            Case Is = "CATEGORYb"
                iCATEGORYb = iCATEGORYb + 1
                
            Case Is = "CATEGORYc"
                iCATEGORYc = iCATEGORYc + 1
                
            Case Else
                iNone = iNone + 1
        End Select
        
    Next olItem
    
    categFolder = "CATEGORYa: " & iCATEGORYa & vbCr & _
          "CATEGORYb: " & iCATEGORYb & vbCr & _
          "CATEGORYc: " & iCATEGORYc & vbCr & _
          "Unflagged: " & iNone & vbCr & _
          "" & vbCr
    
    'Debug.Print "oFolder: " & oFolder

    gCateg = gCateg & vbCr & oFolder
    gCateg = gCateg & vbCr & categFolder
    Debug.Print gCateg
    
Next

For Each oSubFolder In currentFolder.Folders
    If oSubFolder.name <> "Deleted Items" Then
        ProcessCatFolders oSubFolder
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub ProcessCatStartFolder(oFolder As Folder)

Dim iCATEGORYa As Long
Dim iCATEGORYb As Long
Dim iCATEGORYc As Long
Dim iNone As Long

Dim olItem As Object    ' A folder may contain other than mailitems
    
Dim categFolder As String

Dim i As Long

For Each olItem In oFolder.Items
    
    Select Case olItem.categories
        Case Is = "CATEGORYa"
        iCATEGORYa = iCATEGORYa + 1
                
        Case Is = "CATEGORYb"
            iCATEGORYb = iCATEGORYb + 1
                
        Case Is = "CATEGORYc"
            iCATEGORYc = iCATEGORYc + 1
                
        Case Else
            iNone = iNone + 1
    End Select
        
Next olItem
    
categFolder = "CATEGORYa: " & iCATEGORYa & vbCr & _
  "CATEGORYb: " & iCATEGORYb & vbCr & _
  "CATEGORYc: " & iCATEGORYc & vbCr & _
  "Unflagged: " & iNone & vbCr & _
  "" & vbCr
    
'Debug.Print "oFolder: " & oFolder

gCateg = gCateg & vbCr & oFolder
gCateg = gCateg & vbCr & categFolder
Debug.Print gCateg

End Sub
```